# How to use the Spring Security Core Plugin with the Neo4j GORM plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, neo4j

I am trying to use the Spring Security Core plugin in a Grails project using the Neo4j GORM plugin.

As far as I can see I have two options:

1. Use the Spring Security Core plugin as is and persist it's data to say MySQL while using Neo4j for the rest of the application data.
2. Use a custom UserDetailsService.

Does anyone have an example of the latter?

pjdv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like the one in the documentation? http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/11%20Custom%20UserDetailsService.html

Comment: Ah somehow missed that! Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since the Neo4j plugin is GORM compliant, spring-security-core's GormUserDetailsService should work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks Stefan - I have followed the instructions, but am now getting the following error:


URI: /boo/j_spring_security_check
Class: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException

Message: No signature of method: org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.getNodeById() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [5SN1GGBbtU8KiwCMVtJP3w==] Possible solutions: getNodeById(long)

Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: do you have a stacktrace for this? As a quick workaround you could probably do in BootStrap.groovy some metaprogramming magic: EmbeddedGraphDatabase.metaClass.getNodeById << { String id -> delegate .getNodeById(id as long)}

Comment: @StefanArmbruster What if i am using Spring-data-neo4j instead of Neo4j plugin,can you provide any solution for this case?

Comment: No, maybe file a separate question for this.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster Ok,i tried neo4j plugin but in embedded mode it is giving error of file lock exception,here is a question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622802/file-lock-exception