# File Lock Exception

Tags: grails, neo4j

I am using neo4j grails plugin for embedded mode. I am getting file lock exception.i make sure,no other process is using this file. i have tried to give super user permission to file use chmod but it didn't work. so how can i resolve it

Exception stack follows ->

### Caused by OverlappingFileLockException: null

```
>> 1154 | tryLock   in java.nio.channels.FileChannel
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    113 | tryLock   in org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel
|     35 | wrapFileChannelLock in org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock
|     93 | getOsSpecificFileLock in     ''
|     92 | tryLock . in org.neo4j.kernel.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction
|     74 | checkLock in org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker
|     44 | start . . in org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter
|    507 | start     in org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance
|    115 | start . . in org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport
|    328 | run       in org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase
|     56 | <init> .  in org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase
|     90 | newDatabase in org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1
|    199 | newGraphDatabase in org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder
|     70 | newEmbeddedDatabase in org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory
|     53 | create .  in org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.embedded.EmbeddedDatabases$Type$3
|     91 | createDatabase in org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.embedded.EmbeddedDatabases
|    109 | createExecutor in     ''
|    146 | createExecutor in org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver
|    131 | createExecutor in org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.Neo4jConnection
|     79 | <init>    in     ''
|     65 | doCreate  in org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.Connections$4
|     80 | create    in org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.Connections
|     42 | connect . in org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver
|     74 | execute   in org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.engine.JdbcCypherEngine
|     80 | setupIndexing in org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.Neo4jDatastore
|     67 | afterPropertiesSet in     ''
|     50 | getObject in org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.bean.factory.Neo4jDatastoreFactoryBean
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

My Data Source is 


dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver"
    // use impermanent graph db, this requires an additional dependency in BuildConfig.groovy:
    // runtime(group:"org.neo4j", name:"neo4j-kernel", version:neo4jVerison, classifier:"tests")
    url = "jdbc:neo4j:file:/home/alok/Documents/db5"
    // uncomment for embedded usage
    //url = "jdbc:neo4j:instance:test"
    // use remote database
    //url = "jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/"
    // disabling autoCommit is crucial!
    properties = [
    defaultAutoCommit: false
    ]
    // username = "sa"
    // password = ""
}
```

Build config is

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.server.port.http = 6768
grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
        mavenRepo 'http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/'
    }

    neo4jVerison="2.0.3"
    dependencies {
        compile("org.neo4j:neo4j-community:$neo4jVerison")
        // this is required if DataSource.groovy uses url = "jdbc:neo4j:mem"
        //runtime(group:"org.neo4j", name:"neo4j-kernel", version:neo4jVerison, classifier:"tests")
        // next four lines are required if you're using embedded/ha *and* you want the webadmin available
        //compile(group:"org.neo4j.app", name:"neo4j-server", version:neo4jVerison)
        // grails dependencies do not properly support maven classifiers, therefor we'll copy that
        // dependency to lib directory
        //runtime(group:"org.neo4j.app", name:"neo4j-server", version:neo4jVerison, classifier:"static-web")
        //runtime('com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.9')
        //runtime('com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.9')
        // add graphviz capabilities
        compile(group:"org.neo4j", name:"neo4j-graphviz", version: neo4jVerison)
        runtime (group:"org.neo4j", name:"neo4j-shell", version: neo4jVerison)
        // uncomment following line if type=rest is used in DataSource.groovy
        //runtime "org.neo4j:neo4j-rest-graphdb:1.9"
        test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0"
    //  runtime(group:"org.neo4j", name:"neo4j-kernel", version:neo4jVerison, classifier:"tests")
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        compile ":neo4j:2.0.0-M02"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.7'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        //runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that might be a bug in the underlying JDBC driver, I forgot to register a shutdown hook for embedded databases by directory.

Comment: thanks, so,we are using grails old plug-in.can we use sdn and grail-plugin both in my application. my requirement is , i want to do spring security with plugin and rest of work with sdn. is it possible ?

Comment: I think the grails plugin v2 is pretty cool. I don't have enough grails knowledge to see if there are any problems with using SDN 3.2.x in Grails.